# Lua os.tempname

Tags: lua, temp

The file names returned by the Lua `os.tempname` function are weak in two respects

1. Unlike most other languages it is not possible to define a custom prefix for the file name
2. The `_6char` suffix that is generated can, with brute force but nevertheless, be guessed

I have at times used a, salted, MD5 of the current epoch time + a random number.  About the only reason why that "feels" like a better solution is the length of the file name string.

Is there a way to generate better ( = longer?) file names?

Comment: Why would anybody brute-force temp file name?  The name is guaranteed to be unique.  It is not required for the temp file name to be unpredictable.

Comment: In the context where I am need temp files there is a possibility, albeit slender, that someone guessing a name happens and leads to trouble. The fact that Lua offers a guarantee that those names will be unique will not help there.

Comment: The guarantees are given by [mkstemp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) OS function.

Comment: The name of the standard library function is actually `os.tmpname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The purpose of this Lua function is *only* to provide a *unique* name.
2. There are not many options in the standard Lua library.

In other words, either you use what's available in Lua, or you write your own function. However, even if you use hashes, random numbers, and so on, you are still dealing with probability: Such file could exist there since the uniqueness is not guaranteed by the OS in this case.

By the way, consider use of `io.tmpfile` instead of `os.tmpname`.